# setting up MockMVC for Spring Restful Web Service

Tags: spring, rest, mockito, mockmvc

So I don't think there is a lot of questions on here on Mockmvc from spring for testing springmvc controllers but I read through the spring tutorial 
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/2/
where there is a lot there but I was just trying to do a simple GET on a web service with a single id parameter. The controller looked like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demandrest")
public class DemandServicesController {

    @Autowired
    DemandService demandService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/demand/{$id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers= "Accept-application/jsson")
    public Demand readDemand(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) String id){
        return demandService.readDemand(new Long(id));
    }
```

and I wrote a unit test that uses the org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc and I attempt to mock out (really stub) the service call and do an assert on the status code and am getting status code 404. My test looks like this

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

public class DemandServicesControllerTest {

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    DemandServicesController demandServicesController = new DemandServicesController();

    @Mock
    DemandService demandService;

    @Before
    public void setUpUnitTest() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(demandServicesController).
                setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).build();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testReadDemandState() throws Exception {
        Long id = new Long(99);
    Demand demand = new Demand();
        demand.setDescription("description");
        when(demandService.readDemand(id)).thenReturn(demand );
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/demandrest/demand/{id}",id.toString()).
                accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

I couple other things I'll mention before I hit post. So looking at the example from the tutorial I tried to just pick the stuff that I would only use so it isn't an exact copy. One big difference I had to do, and I suspect this has something to do with how in the pom the testing plugin is configured, I had to instantiate the controller where the example is smart enough to know to create an instance. Also, the example relies on Gradle for project set up and I just have a pom file with this project. Not sure if that makes a difference. Seems like this is new stuff but this is a pretty simple example. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix you RequestMapping from

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demand/{$id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers= "Accept-application/jsson")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demand/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers= "Accept=application/json")
```

`{$id}` should be just {id} and `headers` have a typo and incorrect syntax. Perhaps you should consider using `produces` and `consumes` instead of the `headers` param also.

This should fix the 404 status.